# Multiple tables of contents with unnumbered parts

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, numbering, etoc

I want to make a 3-part document that has two tables of contents listing the sections in the second and third parts of the document, respectively. All the parts need to be unnumbered, and the tables and figure numbering needs to restart in each part. I'm trying to make this work in `etoc` but without success so far. Here's what I've tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoc}
\begin{document}

\part*{}

Main paper text and tables here; no table of contents for this part.

\newpage
\setcounter{page}{0}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}

\part*{Online Appendix}
\localtableofcontents
\section{Green}
\section{Blue}
\etocsetlocaltop.toc{part}

\newpage
\setcounter{page}{0}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{SI\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{SI\arabic{table}}

\setcounter{section}{0}

\part*{Supplementary Information}
\localtableofcontents
\section{Red}
\section{White}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{...}` after a non-numbered part.

I added a `\etocsettocstyle` to better visualize the local TOC.

[image: a]

[image: b]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoc}
\etocsettocstyle{\subsection*{\contentsname}}{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{.4pt}} % added <<<< optional

\begin{document}
    
    \part*{}
    
    Main paper text and tables here; no table of contents for this part.
    
    \newpage
    \setcounter{page}{0}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \setcounter{figure}{0}
    \setcounter{table}{0}
    \renewcommand{\thefigure}{A\arabic{figure}}
    \renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}
    
    \part*{Online Appendix}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Online Appendix}
    \localtableofcontents
    \section{Green}
    \section{Blue}
    %\etocsetlocaltop.toc{part}
    
    \newpage
    \setcounter{page}{0}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \setcounter{figure}{0}
    \setcounter{table}{0}
    \renewcommand{\thefigure}{SI\arabic{figure}}
    \renewcommand{\thetable}{SI\arabic{table}}
    
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    
    \part*{Supplementary Information}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Supplementary Information}
    \localtableofcontents
    \section{Red}
    \section{White}
    
\end{document}
```

Alternatively use

```
    \part*{Online Appendix}
    \etocsetlocaltop.toc{part}
    \localtableofcontents
```

at least in this case the result is the same.